# Streaming rows from Android Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a SQLite table (with more than 100000 rows) that I want its rows streamed.

I do:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM hugetable", new String[] {});
```

The problem is that just getting the first row as:

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

seems to load the whole table, being quite slow.

Is there a way to stream a query without having wait to load all the rows when fetching the first row?

(like I can do with the plain C SQLite API outside Android)

Answer (score 1):

The Android `Cursor` is designed to load all data for caching.

To work arouns this, you have to manually query the data in steps:

```
SELECT _id
FROM hugetable
ORDER BY _id
LIMIT 100;

SELECT _id
FROM hugetable
WHERE _id > last_id_from_previous_query
ORDER BY _id
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: I did not know Android did not allow this use case as many database APIs do.
Having to make multiple queries requires parsing each query and building a query plan for each witch reduces performance.
I have requested this use case in the Android database API:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42605